# Alter Hive External table output having array<string> column to support postgresql compatible csv file

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, external-tables, hive-udf

I'm struggle to generate a postgresql compatible tsv format having array as hive-column-type using hive sql having external-table definition.

With Hive I can specify to use delimiter/collection-item-termination to write array field in csv.

however postgresql COPY command requires tsv in format : {data1,data2,data3}